# Android sync listView scrolling

Tags: android, user-interface, listview

I'm trying to sync scrolling of different `listView`.
The issue is that the scrolling behavior(speed and velocity when fling) is different when height's listview is different.
I got simple listView and two double(two element visible) above and below. It works fine when scroll from the simple but not from double. When double fling : the simple scroll but not enough to follow the double; so the double go to the end and stop and simple stop as well but before the end.

This is what I'm trying to do (with centerList with different row height and text size/color, in this case I need ratio to the sync scrolling this is my next step): 
[image: result]

code :

```
public class Stack extends Activity {

@Bind(R.id.create_envent_date_picker_center_list)
ListView centerListView;
@Bind(R.id.create_envent_date_picker_top_list)
ListView topListView;
@Bind(R.id.create_envent_date_picker_bot_list)
ListView botListView;
private int mainScroll = 0;
private Set<ListView> listSetDay = new HashSet<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_create_event_date);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM", Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar todayCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
        myList.add(sdf.format(todayCal.getTime()));
        todayCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }

    ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.add(" ");
    tmp.add(" ");
    tmp.add("DAY");
    tmp.addAll(myList);
    topListView.setAdapter(new DatePickerAdapter(this,
            tmp, R.layout.row_date_picker_darker));
    topListView.setTag(R.id.TAG, 0);
    topListView.setTag(R.id.USERSCROLL, false);
    listSetDay.add(topListView);

    tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.add("DAY");
    tmp.addAll(myList);
    centerListView.setAdapter(new DatePickerAdapter(this,
            tmp, R.layout.row_date_picker_highlight));
    centerListView.setTag(R.id.TAG, 1);
    centerListView.setTag(R.id.USERSCROLL, false);
    listSetDay.add(centerListView);

    tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.clear();
    tmp.addAll(myList);
    tmp.add(" ");
    tmp.add(" ");
    botListView.setAdapter(new DatePickerAdapter(this,
            tmp, R.layout.row_date_picker_darker));
    botListView.setTag(R.id.TAG, 2);
    botListView.setTag(R.id.USERSCROLL, false);
    listSetDay.add(botListView);

    topListView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    centerListView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    botListView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    topListView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollChangeListener);
    centerListView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollChangeListener);
    botListView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollChangeListener);

}

private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if (mainScroll != ((int) v.getTag(R.id.TAG))) {
                for (ListView listView : listSetDay) {
                    if (((int) listView.getTag(R.id.TAG)) != ((int) v.getTag(R.id.TAG)))
                        listView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0);
                }
            }
        mainScroll = ((int) v.getTag(R.id.TAG));
        return false;
    }
};


private AbsListView.OnScrollListener onScrollChangeListener = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView viewScroll, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                         int totalItemCount) {
        // PREVENT AUTO SCROLL IF THE LIST IS NOT SCROLL BY USER
        if (((int) viewScroll.getTag(R.id.TAG)) != mainScroll) {
            return;
        }
        if (viewScroll.getChildAt(0) != null) {
            // GET Y SCROLL OF SCROLLING LIST
            final int ySelected = -viewScroll.getChildAt(0).getTop() +
                    viewScroll.getFirstVisiblePosition() * viewScroll.getChildAt(0).getHeight();

            for (ListView listView : listSetDay) {
                if (((int) listView.getTag(R.id.TAG)) != ((int) viewScroll.getTag(R.id.TAG))) {
                    if (viewScroll.getChildAt(0) != null && listView.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                        // GET Y SCROLL OF THE OTHER LIST
                        final int yOther = -listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() +
                                listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() * listView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
                        // SCROLL OTHER LIST WITH DISTANCE
                        listView.smoothScrollBy(ySelected - yOther, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
}
```

layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/status_bar_height">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/create_envent_date_picker_top_list"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:scrollbars="none">

</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/create_envent_date_picker_center_list"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/create_envent_date_picker_top_list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/create_envent_date_picker_bot_list"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/create_envent_date_picker_center_list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:scrollbars="none">

</ListView>
```

Element of listView only fontColor change for the centerList:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="36dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_picker_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text=""
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/darker or white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_25" />

</LinearLayout>
```